# Multiple default controllers for a route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

short question:

Is there a way to configure multiple default controllers in a route??

Long explanation:

I am creating something similar to a [portable area](http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib/) in MVC 5.
Specifically, I want to create a kind of default controller that will be fired from my portable component if the user does not create it in his application. To be more precise:

- Let's say I have an MVC application that installs my framework via NuGet.
- This component installs a bunch of views in the `_framework` folder, and a DLL gets referenced and the MVC application starts inheriting from my `FrameworkHTTPApplication`.
- That base class configures by default some stuff, like the framework's view Engine that searches for views in the `_framework` folder, and the default routes.
- Now I want the application to be able to create or not their `HomeController`: If they don't create it, the framework will call `FrameworkHomeController` (inside the framework DLL), but if they do create one, it gets served on hitting ~/ .

I was able to create the default controller in the framework, and hook it up correctly, but it will not fall back. This is what routeDebugger is showing me: [image: routes]

As you see I have both routes configured (same URL, different defaults). What I am expecting would be: if controller `Home` does not exist, then `FrameworkHome` should be called.

I have played with the namespaces, but the result is the same.

Any clue on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this using a single route and prioritizing the controllers in the application namespace over the controllers in the framework namespace.

Let´s say the application controllers are defined in the namespace `MyApplication.Controllers` and the framework controllers are defined in the namespace `Framework.Controllers`.

For the root url `/` you want the application to match the controller:

- `MyApplication.Controllers.HomeController` if defined
- Otherwise the controller `Framework.Controllers.HomeController` (note this is also named HomeController and not FrameworkHomeController, however it is defined in the framework namespace)

This is achieved with a single default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "MyApplication.Controllers" }                
);
```

Tha namespaces defined in the route are given priority when multiple matching controllers are found. So for the root url `/` the default controller name `Home` is used, and if the system finds 2 controllers `MyApplication.Controllers.HomeController` and `Framework.Controllers.HomeController` then the one in the namespace `MyApplication.Controllers` will be used.

Comment: It worked beautifully. One thing I got wrong was the namespace; I added it without the `Controllers` part and that was an issue. Once I changed the route to use the whole namespace it started working perfectly.